# C++ exception in 'nativeFlushQueueImmediate' when trying to access firebase on react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using https://rnfirebase.io in react native, and I'm getting this strange error when trying to call firebase sign in with phone

```
 submit() {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(this.phoneInput)
      .then(confirmResult => console.log(confirmResult))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

What could it be?

[image: error]

Comment: Is signInWithPhoneNumber expecting a string? I would attempt to comment out line by line that function to see where the real problem lies. I had this error with the moment js library. Sometimes react native's ability to parse objects and date times is broken.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I ended up deleting the project at all, and load it again from git. Maybe it was something with npm package I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you've updated a native dependancy via npm but have not rebuilt the native side of your app.

The JS bundle will generally have the latest code immediately (after packager restart) but the native side will not until you rebuild your app on xcode/studio; therefore causing argument mismatches across React Native's bridge as both could be expecting very different arguments based on their previous versions.

The same applies in reverse, you've re-built your native app but not restarted the packager after updating a native dependancy via npm.